# Extract return type of functions from metadata

Tags: oracle, functions, metadata

I want to identify all my stored functions which return REFCURSOR.

Is there a way to do that?

I can't find this information anywhere.

I searched in dba_functions,dba_objects,dba_arguments...

What is the (best) way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a quick and simple test:

[ALL_ARGUMENTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_ARGUMENTS.html)

```
select * from
all_arguments
where
position = 0
and data_level = 0
and argument_name is null
and data_type = 'REF CURSOR';
```

position 0 is the first argument of a program unit. If it does not have a name/level (`data_level = 0 and argument_name is null`), then it is the return argument of the function, and you are looking for `sys_refcursor` type, which is displayed as `REF CURSOR` in this view.